# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, django, windows-10, pycharm

Tenho o seguinte problema entre duas apps, na qual faço a chamada de um model de uma app (app1) em uma view de uma outra app (app2)

```
Projeto
  ├ APP1
  └ APP2
```

---

View da APP2:

```
from projeto.app1.models import ObjetoX

objeto_x = ObjetoX(parm=1)
```

---

Ao fazer isso surge o seguinte erro:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projeto.app1'

**IDE**: PyCharm
**Sistema Operacional**: Windows 10

Comment: o nome do arquivo esta maiúsculo ou minusculo?

Comment: Rodrigo, não alterei o nome das pastas pois é relevante para as respostas..

Comment: Suas apps estão listadas no settings.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
from app1.models import ObjetoX

objeto_x = ObjetoX(parm=1)
```